# Mysql choosing really poor index without IGNORE INDEX hint

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, index-tuning, mysql-8.0, hints

### **Problem**

The following query produces a really inefficient query plan:

```
select `event`.`id` as `eventId` 
from `alert`
inner join `event` on `event`.`id` = `alert`.`eventId` 
inner join `property` on `property`.`id` = `event`.`propertyId`
inner join `landlord` on `landlord`.`id` = `property`.`landlordId`
where `landlord`.`reference` in ( 
     'landlord1',
     'landlord2',
     'landlord3',
     'landlord4',
     'landlord5',
     'landlord6',
     'landlord7',   
     'landlord8'
)
order by `alert`.`raiseddate` desc limit 20;
```

**Query plan:**

[image]
The index of note here is `` alert_eventIdRaisedDate on Alert(`eventId`,`raisedDate` DESC) ``

**Timing:**  4008ms

By forcing mysql to ignore a specific index, things are much much faster.

```
select `event`.`id` as `eventId` 
from `alert` ignore index (alert_eventIdRaisedDate)
inner join `event` on `event`.`id` = `alert`.`eventId` 
inner join `property` on `property`.`id` = `event`.`propertyId`
inner join `landlord` on `landlord`.`id` = `property`.`landlordId`
where `landlord`.`reference` in ( 
     'landlord1',
     'landlord2',
     'landlord3',
     'landlord4',
     'landlord5',
     'landlord6',
     'landlord7',   
     'landlord8'
)
order by `alert`.`raiseddate` desc limit 20;
```

**Query plan:**

[image]

**Timing:** 83ms

If we execute the query without a landlord where clause, no hint is required and it's really fast.

```
select `event`.`id` as `eventId` 
from `alert` 
inner join `event` on `event`.`id` = `alert`.`eventId` 
inner join `property` on `property`.`id` = `event`.`propertyId`
inner join `landlord` on `landlord`.`id` = `property`.`landlordId`
order by `alert`.`raiseddate` desc limit 20;
```

**Query Plan:**

[image]

**Timing:** 18ms

### Thoughts

I believe the performance penalty without the index hint is incurred due to `using temporary, using file sort` which means mysql is not able to satisfy the order by clause from an index.  `` alert_eventIdRaisedDate on Alert(`eventId`,`raisedDate` DESC) ``, so why is my sql choosing this index and what can be done to either the query, schema or indexes to remove the need for the ignore index hint?

I have tested this on both mysql 5.7 and mysql 8, same same. Details captured in this question are from mysql 8.0

#### Schema

```
CREATE TABLE `alert` (
  `id` char(36) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `value` decimal(10,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `valueUnitId` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `eventId` char(36) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `test` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `typeId` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `statusId` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `raisedDate` datetime(3) NOT NULL,
  `resolvedDate` datetime(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
  `updatedAt` datetime(3) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
  `snoozedUntil` datetime(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `autoCancel` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `resolvingEventId` char(36) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `eventId_UNIQUE` (`eventId`) /*!80000 INVISIBLE */,
  UNIQUE KEY `alert_EventIdTypeIdStatusIdUnique` (`eventId`,`typeId`,`statusId`) /*!80000 INVISIBLE */,
  KEY `valueUnitId` (`valueUnitId`),
  KEY `test` (`test`),
  KEY `typeId` (`typeId`),
  KEY `alert_resolvingEventId_foreign_idx` (`resolvingEventId`),
  KEY `idx_alert_raisedDateEventIdStatusId` (`raisedDate`,`statusId`,`eventId`),
  KEY `alert_raisedDate` (`raisedDate`),
  KEY `alert_eventIdStatusId` (`eventId`,`statusId`) /*!80000 INVISIBLE */,
  KEY `alert_idEventIdStatusId` (`id`,`eventId`,`statusId`),
  KEY `alert_eventIdId` (`eventId`,`id`) /*!80000 INVISIBLE */,
  KEY `alert_idEventId` (`id`,`eventId`),
  KEY `alert_statusIdTypeIdEventId` (`statusId`,`typeId`,`eventId`),
  KEY `alert_EventIdTypeIdStatusId` (`eventId`,`typeId`,`statusId`) /*!80000 INVISIBLE */,
  KEY `alert_eventIdRaisedDate` (`eventId`,`raisedDate` DESC),
  KEY `alert_raisedDateEventId` (`raisedDate` DESC,`eventId`),
  CONSTRAINT `alert_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`valueUnitId`) REFERENCES `measurementunit` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `alert_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`eventId`) REFERENCES `event` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `alert_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`test`) REFERENCES `measurementunit` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `alert_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`typeId`) REFERENCES `alerttype` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `alert_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`statusId`) REFERENCES `alertstatus` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `alert_resolvingEventId_foreign_idx` FOREIGN KEY (`resolvingEventId`) REFERENCES `event` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `event` (
  `id` char(36) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `createdAt` datetime(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
  `updatedAt` datetime(3) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
  `eventTypeId` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `sourceId` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `deviceId` char(36) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `propertyId` char(36) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `raisedDate` datetime(3) NOT NULL,
  `insightId` char(36) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `raisedYear` int GENERATED ALWAYS AS (year(`raisedDate`)) STORED,
  `raisedMonth` int GENERATED ALWAYS AS (month(`raisedDate`)) STORED,
  `raisedDay` int GENERATED ALWAYS AS (dayofmonth(`raisedDate`)) STORED,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `event_UNIQUE` (`deviceId`,`insightId`,`propertyId`,`raisedDate`,`eventTypeId`) /*!80000 INVISIBLE */,
  UNIQUE KEY `event_DEVICE` (`deviceId`,`raisedDate`,`eventTypeId`) /*!80000 INVISIBLE */,
  UNIQUE KEY `event_INSIGHT` (`insightId`,`raisedDate`,`eventTypeId`) /*!80000 INVISIBLE */,
  KEY `sourceId` (`sourceId`) /*!80000 INVISIBLE */,
  KEY `idx_eventtypeId_id` (`eventTypeId`,`id`) /*!80000 INVISIBLE */,
  KEY `idx_eventType_deviceId_raisedDate` (`eventTypeId`,`deviceId`,`raisedDate`) /*!80000 INVISIBLE */,
  KEY `event_propertyIdRaisedDate` (`propertyId`,`raisedDate`),
  KEY `event_raiseDate` (`raisedDate`),
  KEY `event_eventTypeIdraiseDate` (`eventTypeId`,`raisedDate`) /*!80000 INVISIBLE */,
  KEY `event_eventTypeIdPropertyidraiseDate` (`eventTypeId`,`propertyId`,`raisedDate`),
  KEY `event_raisedDatePropertyId` (`raisedDate`,`propertyId`) /*!80000 INVISIBLE */,
  KEY `event_raisedDateDESC` (`raisedDate` DESC),
  KEY `event_propertyIdRaisedDateDESC` (`propertyId`,`raisedDate` DESC),
  CONSTRAINT `event_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`eventTypeId`) REFERENCES `eventtype` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `event_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`sourceId`) REFERENCES `source` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `event_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`deviceId`) REFERENCES `device` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `event_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`propertyId`) REFERENCES `property` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `event_insightId_foreign_idx` FOREIGN KEY (`insightId`) REFERENCES `insight` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `property` (
  `id` char(36) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `reference` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `parentId` char(36) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `landlordId` char(36) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `addressId` int NOT NULL,
  `geoId` int NOT NULL,
  `typeId` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `statusId` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `constructionTypeId` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `heatingTypeId` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `constructionDate` datetime(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
  `updatedAt` datetime(3) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
  `propertyFloorId` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `buildingTypeId` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `isStock` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdBy` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'SYSTEM',
  `displayReference` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deletedBy` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `designationId` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'DOMESTIC',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `reference` (`reference`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_isStockUnique` (`isStock`,`landlordId`),
  KEY `parentId` (`parentId`),
  KEY `landlordId` (`landlordId`),
  KEY `addressId` (`addressId`),
  KEY `geoId` (`geoId`),
  KEY `typeId` (`typeId`),
  KEY `constructionTypeId` (`constructionTypeId`),
  KEY `heatingTypeId` (`heatingTypeId`),
  KEY `property_propertyFloorId_foreign_idx` (`propertyFloorId`),
  KEY `property_buildingTypeId_foreign_idx` (`buildingTypeId`),
  KEY `idx_propertyId` (`id`),
  KEY `idx_propertyReference` (`reference`),
  KEY `idx_propertyPropertyStatusId` (`statusId`),
  KEY `property_designationId_foreign_idx` (`designationId`),
  CONSTRAINT `property_buildingTypeId_foreign_idx` FOREIGN KEY (`buildingTypeId`) REFERENCES `buildingtype` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `property_designationId_foreign_idx` FOREIGN KEY (`designationId`) REFERENCES `propertydesignation` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `property_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`parentId`) REFERENCES `property` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `property_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`landlordId`) REFERENCES `landlord` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `property_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`addressId`) REFERENCES `address` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `property_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`geoId`) REFERENCES `geo` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `property_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`typeId`) REFERENCES `propertytype` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `property_ibfk_6` FOREIGN KEY (`statusId`) REFERENCES `propertystatus` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `property_ibfk_7` FOREIGN KEY (`constructionTypeId`) REFERENCES `constructiontype` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `property_ibfk_8` FOREIGN KEY (`heatingTypeId`) REFERENCES `heatingtype` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `property_propertyFloorId_foreign_idx` FOREIGN KEY (`propertyFloorId`) REFERENCES `propertyfloor` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `landlord` (
  `id` char(36) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `reference` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
  `updatedAt` datetime(3) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `totalHousingStock` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `statusId` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postcode` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contactName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contactEmail` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contactPhone` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `allowPropertyCreation` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `createdBy` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'SYSTEM',
  `typeId` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parentReference` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `designationId` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'PROVIDER',
  `internal` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `reference` (`reference`),
  KEY `landlord_statusId_foreign_idx` (`statusId`),
  KEY `landlord_typeId_foreign_idx` (`typeId`),
  KEY `landlord_designationId_foreign_idx` (`designationId`),
  KEY `landlord_parentreferenceId` (`parentReference`,`id`) /*!80000 INVISIBLE */,
  CONSTRAINT `landlord_designationId_foreign_idx` FOREIGN KEY (`designationId`) REFERENCES `landlorddesignation` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `landlord_parentReference_foreign_idx` FOREIGN KEY (`parentReference`) REFERENCES `landlord` (`reference`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `landlord_statusId_foreign_idx` FOREIGN KEY (`statusId`) REFERENCES `landlordstatus` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `landlord_typeId_foreign_idx` FOREIGN KEY (`typeId`) REFERENCES `landlordtype` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Try to renew data statistic (ANALYZE TABLE).

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned, already tried this.

Comment: Beware -- You may find that a different set of landlords leads to a slower query when using the `IGNORE`.

Comment: You can improve things slightly by eliminating the use of the table `event`.

Comment: @RickJames Thanks for the comments, I'm aware of the issues with using IGNORE which is why I was trying to understand how to avoid it's usage. Regarding eliminating the use of the event table, I can only achieve that by denormalising `propertyId` or `landlordid` and including that on the Alert table, otherwise I have no relation to landlord on which to filter?

Comment: @SamShiles - When the Optimizer analyzes a query with `INNER JOINs` and a `WHERE` clause filtering on a single table, it will _usually_ start with that table.  So, the most help the query writer can do, is realize this and build indexes to help with that `WHERE`, and then table-by-table the `JOINs` to the rest of the tables.  In some situations, this works nicely; in some it is not clean, and denormalization is tempting.

Comment: Multiple JOINs often involve a [_Many-to-many_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) table.  Novices often index this inefficiently.  That's another quick (but partial) fix for performance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure all the tables involved in this query are all one-to-many? It feels crazy that after SQL being around for 50+ years that I'm so often able to hint one of the most popular RDMS (mysql) into choosing a query plan that is orders of magnitude faster than the one it select it's self. I've used MS SQL a lot in the past and don't remember experiencing this many poorly optimised query plans. Does mysql have a particularity poor optimiser? I'm tempted to export my data into another RDMS and see how it compares, or am I wasting my time? Any thoughts gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your query and I found that when it uses the `alert_raisedDateEventId` index, there is no `Using filesort` in the EXPLAIN report. That's why it's using that index, so it can read the rows from the index in the same order that you want them sorted, therefore the `ORDER BY` is a no-op.

But this means the first row of the EXPLAIN shows it's doing `type: index` which means an index-scan. It has to read every entry in that index, even though after it does all the joins, many of them might be eliminated.

The other joins are all `type: eq_ref` which means joining to the respective tables' primary keys. This is an efficient way to do the joins, and the optimizer prefers it. So the combination of no filesort and joins by primary key makes the optimizer happy.

Try this query:

```
explain select `event`.`id` as `eventId`
from `landlord`
inner join `property` on `landlord`.`id` = `property`.`landlordId`
inner join `event` on `property`.`id` = `event`.`propertyId`
inner join `alert` on `event`.`id` = `alert`.`eventId`
where `landlord`.`reference` in (
     'landlord1',
     'landlord2',
     'landlord3',
     'landlord4',
     'landlord5',
     'landlord6',
     'landlord7',
     'landlord8'
)
order by `alert`.`raiseddate` desc limit 20
```

`landlord` should use its `reference` index to make that condition be a range lookup, to select a subset of the rows in `landlord`, and then the subsequent tables are joined to that result. The joins will be by non-primary indexes, but that might be okay.

But it will also force `alert` to be the last table joined, and you can't get rid of the filesort in that case. You can only optimize the filesort away if the order is based on an indexed column of the first table in the series of joins. This might not be a problem if the result set after all the joins have been applied is pretty small.

You might have to use `from landlord force index(reference)` if the optimizer tries to reorder the tables back to the original plan.

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to investigate and reply, really appreciate it. Your `from landlord` query gives me the same plan and performance as my original query without the ignore index hint. Which isn't surprising as my original query was already doing a range lookup using the landlord reference index. I actually find this somewhat reassuring as I'd hope the optimiser was good enough to reorder joins based on it's stats. It's curious that your test resulted in it using `alert_raisedDateEventId`, for me it always use `alert_eventIdRaisedDate` unless I hint

Comment: I'm testing with empty tables, which often causes anomalous results from the optimizer.